# Reading an X.509 certificate with Java

Tags: java, certificate, saml

I am trying to use Java to read a certificate that I received from an external party. The code is throwing the following error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Unable to initialize, java.io.IOException: extra data given to DerValue constructor

The code:

```
FileInputStream ksfis = new FileInputStream(this.getCertificateFile());
ksbufin = new BufferedInputStream(ksfis);
certificate = (X509Certificate)
  CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCertificate(ksbufin);
```

To make sure the problem was not in the code, I created a self-signed certificate and used it with the code, and it worked fine. I have installed both certificates in the system key chain, and they both are valid. I am using a Mac and Java 1.6.

Any idea why I get the above exception when I load the external Party certificate? Do you think it got corrupted during transfer? If it did, it should not show up as valid on the local system, right?

Comment: If you open it in a text editor, does it show text or garbage?

Comment: I opened mine in the text editor and its complete garbage and the third party one is neatly arranged junk inside BEGIN Certificate and END certificate text and the content inside these two ends with ==(base64 encoded?)

Comment: thanks.Do I have to use Bouncy castle to read it then or there is some other option in java? and also what is the default format(the one on my self signed certificate)?

Comment: DER is normally used, PEM is for mail and is the default for openssl. Try [this](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/openssl/PEMReader.html) there is no Java decoder for PEM in the default JRE libraries. You are using a DER (ASN.1) encoded certificate.

Comment: Why is this tagged SAML?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: (because necroed) for the record these comments were and are wrong. Java `CertificateFactory` since at least 1.5 circa 2005 reads either PEM or DER, although before 7 (very near this Q) it couldn't handle PEM with _extra data before_ the PEM block like the 'comments' added by some programs cough OpenSSL cough, and gave an exception that wrongly implied PEM wasn't supported. OTOH `KeyFactory` was and is only DER, and `KeyStore` only binary (DER for PKCS12, Java-serial for JKS and JCEKS, but not PEM). And PEM is BEGIN not START, and no spaces between hyphens and words. ...

Comment: ... With OP long gone and no data, we can't know what the problem was, but it _wasn't_ PEM.

Comment: Yeah, true, as I found out to my surprise that the input streams for the `CertificateFactory` do support PEM.

Answer (score 10):

Try to type this using openssl, and then import the result:

```
openssl x509 -outform der -in certificate.pem -out certificate.der
```

or use the Java Bouncy Castle functionality in the lightweight API:

http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/openssl/PEMReader.html

You may encode the result again and then use the `"X509"` `CertificateBuilder` in Java to get a JCE defined certificate, e.g.

```
ByteArrayInputStream certStream  =  new ByteArrayInputStream(binaryCert);
CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) certFactory.generateCertificate(certStream);
```

Comment: FWIW, the BouncyCastle lightweight API gave me a very similar error.

Comment: Not all certificates are created equal, @cmbaron, I've seen many encoding errors. If you are sure your code should work (ask the Bouncy mailing list) then it can be your certificate as well.

Comment: I had the same error as OP and in my case the cause were extra spaces at the end of the lines.