# decoding certificate in Java by DER algorithm

Tags: java, certificate

I have to open cert file in my Java class. Certyficates are encoded by DER algorithm. How can i decode this file ?

I upload certyficate to my servlet, this way

```
InputStream in = getResourceAsStream("/certyficate.cer");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in))
```

now i have to decode this file, how can i do that ?

Now i have have trouble with, get.Instance()

[image]

i used it exactly how it is in documentation, but i have an error like in this screenshot

how can i fix that ?

Comment: you could try the code in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11621414 or something similar using bouncy castle http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/X.509+Public+Key+Certificate+and+Certification+Request+Generation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your `InputStream in` containing the certificate,
 you can decode the certificate
through [`java.security.cert.CertificateFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/CertificateFactory.html#generateCertificate%28java.io.InputStream%29). DER and PEM encodings are supported.

Imports you will need:

```
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
```

To decode the certificate:

```
try {
    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(in);
} catch (CertificateException e) {
    // handle failure to decode certificate
}
```

Comment: Many thx fo answer, but i have an error with this code: "Certificate cannot be converted to X509 certificate". Do you know how can i fix it ?

Comment: Could you show us the certificate data that you are providing in the `InputStream` ?

Comment: it was ordinary certificate from windows's certmgr.msc. Error was with throws, but i fixed it. Thx for help

Answer (score 1):

Well you can't use a `Reader`, for a start. It's binary. This task is done via [`java.security.CertificateFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/CertificateFactory.html).