# How to read information of certificate files with different file extensions in Java?

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, certificate

Can I read/extract information of every file extension (.pem, .der, .crt, .cert) with the following code in Java or is this just working with .crt-files?

```
CertificateFactory fac = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("\\path\\to\\file\\cert.crt");
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) fac.generateCertificate(is);
System.out.println("From: " + cert.getNotBefore());
System.out.println("Until: " + cert.getNotAfter());
```

If not, how can I read certificate files of any type/file extension? Is there an library?

Answer (score 0):

It's more a matter of data types than of file extends.
PEM encoded key stuff and certificates can easily be read with BouncyCastel library. A good point to start is Baeldung's tutorial [Introduction to BouncyCastle](https://www.baeldung.com/java-bouncy-castle). Also a good point to dig into is [Bouncy Castle's github](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java).

For DER encoded stuff the answer of the question [decoding certificate in Java by DER algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32998184/decoding-certificate-in-java-by-der-algorithm) may be a point to start.