# KeyStore.load method throws java.io.IOException : extra data given to DerValue constructor

Tags: java, security, x509certificate, x509

I was looking for a solution,but nothing I have already found solved my problem.
I am trying to simply add a new Key to an existing KeyStore file,but it seemes like I can't add more than one Key, cause this exceptions occurs on the second call of function for adding a new Key in main method and on the bolded KeyStore.load method.
Here is my method:

```
    String keyPass="pass"; 

    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
    char[] storePass = this.keyStorePass.toCharArray();
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(this.keyStoreName);
    **keyStore.load(is,storePass);** 
    is.close();

    Certificate[] certChain = new Certificate[1];  
    certChain[0] = this.certificate;  
    keyStore.setKeyEntry(key, this.pair.getPrivate(), keyPass.toCharArray(), certChain); 

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(this.keyStoreName);
    keyStore.store(fos, storePass);
    fos.close();
```

Here is the exception:

```
   `java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: java.io.IOException:
    extra data given to DerValue constructor
   at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.<init>(Unknown Source)
   at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
   at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
   at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate
   at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate
   at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad
   at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
   at java.security.KeyStore.load(Unknown Source)
   at zp2016.StorageClass.addToMyKeyStore(StorageClass.java:76)
   at zp2016.MainProgram.main(MainProgram.java:76)
```

`

Certificate chain has 1 element, cause the app is about self-signed X509 certificate.Thanks.

Comment: editing your post to show us the exception will definitely help.

Comment: I have edited it,thanks.

Comment: Looks like you're getting exception when reading the keystore, not adding a new cert. Have you seen this SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621414/reading-an-x-509-certificate-with-java

Comment: Yes,but it didn't solve my problem :/

Comment: I have found a solution.A problem was with adding a certificate extension,it has nothing to do with loading a keyStore.Thanks anyway :)