# java.security.cert.CertificateException: Unable to initialize

Tags: java, certificate, digital-signature, saml-2.0, opensaml

Hello i try to validate a certifacte against another and getting an error while reading the first Certificate form a file:

```
//Get Public Key
BasicX509Credential publicCredential = new BasicX509Credential();
File publicKeyFile = new File("keys/azurecert.cer");

if (publicKeyFile.exists()) {
    CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    InputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(publicKeyFile);
    X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate)certificateFactory.generateCertificate(fileStream);
            fileStream.close();
```

The `azurecert.cer` was generated by me and its content was copy pasted from azures (adfs) federationmetadata.xml. Is this a Problem?

```
<KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <X509Data>
        <X509Certificate>
            MIIC4jCC....
        </X509Certificate>
    </X509Data>
</KeyInfo>
```

and i put it in this format:

```
—–--BEGIN CERTIFICATE--—–  
MIIDBTCCAe2gAwIBAgIQPLxWKJFunNyLetteErs/DAtQPLxWKJFunNyLMMFsdioT
MSswKQYDVQQDEyJhY2NvdW50cy5hFunNyLetteErsndpbmRvd3MubmV0XHhsStcm
....
----END CERTIFICATE----
```

But it results in:

```
java.security.cert.CertificateException: Unable to initialize, java.io.IOException: extra data given to DerValue constructor
```

at line:

```
certificateFactory.generateCertificate(inputStream2)
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you have the correct headers. Instead of `—–BEGIN CERTIFICATE—–` and `--END CERTIFICATE--` use

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Alternatively you can read the certificate in binary format: remove BEGIN CERTIFICATE and END CERTIFICATE tags and decode the base64

Comment: oh yes that was a problem something went wrong during the process... i have updated the question

Comment: Your code is correct. Seems a problem with the content of the certificate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621414/reading-an-x-509-certificate-with-java. Try to save as binary `.crt` as I wrote in answer and open it with double click (windows), or import/export with openssl (see the link). If the content can be public, copy it in the question and I will take a look