# Run Keycloak with GoogleCloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, keycloak, google-cloud-run

I am currently running keycloak with kubernetes with no problems. everything works as expected but I would like to switch to cloud run(fully managed) and for now keycloak is giving me some problems:

I noticed that in cloud run you cannot connect trough tcp to the mysql database(google sql 2nd generation), but I did not find any documentation on how to set up keycloak to use socket connection.
Is this currently possible with keycloak?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should probably ask on [Keycloak's community forum](https://keycloak.discourse.group/) about how it can be configured to use a local Unix domain socket to connect to MySQL.

It's also worth noting that certain kinds of applications are suitable for Cloud Run, and you should evaluate if Keycloak fits these requirements:

- HTTP-based traffic (HTTP1/2, gRPC etc), other sorts of traffic (e.g. arbitrary TCP, UDP) will not work.
- No sidecar containers (Kubernetes supports this, but Cloud Run does not)
- Stateless application: Cloud Run will scale your app to multiple instances, or kill it due to inactivity (no incoming requests), Keycloak must be tolerant to this.
- No background processing: Application container is suspended when there are no HTTP requests are being processed. If Keycloak relies on a container running at all times in the background, it won't work.
- Local disk space is counted towards memory. Keycloak [claims](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/6.0/server_installation/) it needs at least 1G disk space. On Cloud Run, files written to disk count towards your container’s memory (RAM) limit, so if Keycloak uses a lot of disk, it can crash your container.

Comment: Well you answered my question, there is no need for further investigation. Bullet 3 is a deal breaker and bullet 5 means it is to costly to run it inside Cloud Run.

Comment: Np, glad it helped you. Is Keycloak actually stateful? I would assume it's storing state in an external storage like MySQL as you mentioned. And does it actually use a lot of local filesystem really?

Comment: Based on their documentation it is. It stores some user data in a cache system using Infinispan. There may be workarounds for this but the facts do not change, you answered my question

Comment: Maybe if there is an option to use other memory database you can use GCP memorystore.

Comment: Does this only apply to v1, or v2 as well? Cloudrun v2 has support for filesystem storage now.

Answer (score 2):

we just encountered the same problem and it takes me 1.5 days, until we found a solution. therefore we want to share it, so others may not spend hours to figure this out.

We're using a custom builded docker file for 2 reasons:

- 1. Google Cloud Run does not support tcp-connections to the database and Keycloak has no native support for unix-socket connections. Therefore, whe gonna build it into the existing docker image (see below)
- 2. Installing extensions and themes

### Dockerfile

building image localy or on google cloud: docker build && docker tag... OR gcloud builds submit --region=your-region --tag gcr.io/your-project-id/keycloak
https://github.com/mpbits/dev-ops/blob/main/gcp/keycloak/Dockerfile | https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/11265

building: https://quarkus.io/guides/deploying-to-google-cloud

#### How to update?

just rebuild the docker image and redeploy the cloud run instance

### Mysql / Postgressql JDBC Socket Factory (and others)

A library provided by google explicitly for the use of java applications within cloud run or other serverless environments.
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory/blob/main/docs/jdbc-mysql.md

#### How to update?

1. look for newer version of the connector here: https://storage.googleapis.com/cloud-sql-java-connector/
2. paste them into the current folder
3. update Dockerfile
4. rebuild docker image

Example Docker File:

```
FROM quay.io/phasetwo/phasetwo-keycloak:latest as builder

ENV KC_HEALTH_ENABLED=true
ENV KC_METRICS_ENABLED=true
ENV KC_FEATURES=preview,token-exchange
ENV KC_DB=mysql

# This is needed in order to use com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory
# More at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory/blob/main/docs/jdbc-mysql.md
ENV KC_DB_KIND=mysql
ENV KC_DB_DIALECT=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
COPY mysql-socket-factory-1.8.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar /opt/keycloak/providers/

RUN /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build --transaction-xa-enabled=false --cache=local

FROM quay.io/phasetwo/phasetwo-keycloak:latest

# Install socket for mysql
COPY mysql-socket-factory-1.8.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar /opt/keycloak/providers/

COPY --from=builder /opt/keycloak /opt/keycloak
WORKDIR /opt/keycloak
# for demonstration purposes only, please make sure to use proper certificates in production instead
# RUN keytool -genkeypair -storepass password -storetype PKCS12 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -dname "CN=server" -alias server -ext "SAN:c=DNS:localhost,IP:127.0.0.1" -keystore conf/server.keystore
# change these values to point to a running mysql instance
ENV KC_HEALTH_ENABLED=true
ENV KC_METRICS_ENABLED=true
ENV KC_FEATURES=preview,token-exchange

ENV KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin
ENV KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin

ENV KC_DB=mysql
ENV KC_DB_KIND=mysql
ENV KC_DB_DIALECT=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
ENV KC_TRANSACTION_XA_ENABLED=false

# ENV KC_DB_URL="jdbc:mysql:///keycloak?cloudSqlInstance=<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory"
# ENV KC_DB_USERNAME=<MYSQL_USERNAME>
# ENV KC_DB_PASSWORD=<MYSQL_USER_PASSWORD>

ENV KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT=false
ENV KC_HTTPS_CLIENT_AUTH=request
ENV KC_HTTPS_PORT=8443
ENV KC_HTTPS_PROTOCOLS=TLSv1.3,TLSv1.2
ENV KC_HTTP_ENABLED=true
ENV KC_HTTP_PORT=8080
ENV KC_PROXY=edge
ENV PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh", "start", "--optimized", "--spi-email-template-provider=freemarker-plus-mustache", "--spi-email-template-freemarker-plus-mustache-enabled=true"]
```

Comment: you can also remove the database-connection params and add them later at runtime, if you want to deploy to different environments.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, once I got around Cloud SQL users and account permissions I've managed to get this working on Cloud Run!

Comment: notice: i used the phasetwo docker image, you can of cause use the office docker image as well.

Comment: Hey i followed your doc and i keep getting  ```cloudSqlInstance property not set. Please specify this property in the JDBC URL or the connection Properties with value in form "project:region:instance""``` any idea what im missing ?

Comment: I could get it to work by adding necessary permissions. This helped me thanks @PaulWerner

Comment: @user3398900 there is currently an error, when upgrading to version 22.* from 21.* with the caching. I "solved" it by disabling the cache by passing the --cache=local parameter while building. Have you found a better solution for this?